# How to pass object with redirect::intended and retrieve it in view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

In controller, I get the `$user` object from `Sentry::authenticate`.

```
{"id":44,"email":"test@test.com","permissions":[],"activated":true,"activated_at":null,"last_login":"2014-06-10 09:54:25","first_name":"henry","last_name":"wilson","created_at":"2014-06-02 07:10:38","updated_at":"2014-06-10 09:54:25"}
```

I pass it in view with

```
return View::make('index', array('user'=> $user));
```

and retrieve it as `{{$user->last_name}}, {{$user->email}}`, etc and so on in my view.

How can I pass the same object using `return Redirect::intended()`

I tried doing return `Redirect::intended()->with('user', $user);` however in my view I get Undefined variable exception. I would also like to achieve the same using `Redirect::route()`

Comment: If the user is logged in can't you get their details from `Auth::user()`

Comment: @RMcLeod How that relates to this code? OP's using Sentry, not the Auth class

Comment: @DamienPirsy That's why I asked the question, not used Sentry myself

Comment: I am not using Auth of Laravel but using Sentry. I got the object, passed to the view and retrieved it there. But I would like to be able to do so using Redirect::intended() and Redirect::route().

Answer (score 1):

When using `Redirect::intended()->with('user', $user);` the data is flashed in the session. The data will be available via sessions for this one request.
In your view, you can do something like this in the beginning :

```
<?php
  if(isset(Session::get('user'))) $user = Session::get('user');
?>
```

Then your user variable will be overwritten if it is given within the session. You could also do this within a view composer.

See http://laravel.com/docs/responses#redirects

Comment: The data is available just for a request via session, if I navigate to other pages and return back, it does not exist. How to retain this data while I navigate back and forth without logging out.

Comment: Well I think the easiest way is to use a view composer that gets your user object. You can then add this composer class to all the views that need the user object. If you need it in almost all views you might think about using View::share('name', $data); which shares data across all views.